# how to find important variable using knn in R

Tags: r, knn

I want to upgrade accuracy using KNN algorithm.

I have 23 factors(sex, age, payment, education etc...)

Problem is there are too many variables so i want to know which are effective variables.

[info]

- dataset -> 10000 row, 24 column
- last column is default(1=yes, 0=no)

[image]

I divided 7000 for training set and 3000 for test set. When i use all variables, i got error classification about 1000. Also, using ROC Curve shows 800 error. But i want to reduce error rate more. What method i can do?? 
If you write code example, it will be helpful!! :)

Comment: I think this is better off on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm not completely sure about this, but I think it will not be possible. Since KNN groups observations based on distance I don't think there is a methodological way of accessing each variable importance. Something you could try is vary each one of your variables independently and test how the predictions change.